# Flex/AIR Application Desktop Toolbar

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, air-native-extension

I am currently constructing an AIR application using the Flex framework for deployment on Windows platforms and it would be preferable (for the sake of UX) that the main application window acts as a [Application Desktop Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the right edge of the screen (similar to the new Facebook Desktop Messenger application when "docked").

What is the best way (if any) to perform this using AIR? In the case that there is no solution, can native processes or native extensions be used? If so, how?

Comment: A screenshot would say a lot more than that MSDN page.

Comment: Of course, there are screenshots of the docked Facebook Messenger (which most closely resembles what I am trying to achieve) at the following links: http://sumtips.com/2011/12/download-facebook-messenger-application-for-windows.html, http://www.axleration.com/facebook-messenger-for-windows/

Comment: If I understand, You want to Dock an AIR app to one side of the Windows Desktop?  Can the user do this just by dragging the window to one side and it will dock automatically?  You might be able to simulate docking w/ placement and a custom chrome to prevent the user from moving it; but I'm not sure other windows would honor that. I wouldn't expect AIR to have this functionality available. Perhaps with a Native Extension?

Comment: Indeed, the two problems I have encountered so far are: other windows covering the application and the application not staying on top. I am not an expert in AIR native extensions. Help in regards to how this can be done would be appreciated.

Comment: It is possible using an ANE. You would have to read that MSDN doc and implement that functionality to provide hooks to the air application

Comment: The docking itself shouldn't be too much of an issue: you can use the `Screen` class to get all the information you need. As for making it stay on top: I couldn't think of a solution from the top of my head, so I googled and found [this](http://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2008/12/11/How-do-I-make-an-AIR-Window-be-always-on-top) on @www.Flextras.com's blog ;)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. There is one final issue: other windows must be resized such that they can be fully visible. Does AIR provide any functionality to manipulate the position and size of other windows?

Comment: @RIAstar The issue is more than just keeping it on top; but I guess Chris already discovered that.  In Windows, docking the window means other windows honor that placement and size themselves to never enter the "docked" space.  AIR has no functionality [that I know of] to manipulate the position and size of Windows not part of the AIR application.  AIR can control multiple windows that it creates.

Comment: And for info on Native Extensions, start here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-4aefe03513238d8a1b8-8000.html

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Now I get it. But since there are AutoHotkey scripts out there that can resize windows, I guess it should be feasible to do something similar through `NativeProcess`.

Comment: @RIAstar I didn't even think of NativeProcess, yes I bet that could work; and may be easier than Native Extensions.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `alwaysInFront` to keep the application on top of other windows

in flex:
    `<s:WindowedApplication alwaysInFront="true" ...`

in as3:
    `nativeWindow.alwaysInFront=true;`

As for the docking part, this [link](https://groups.google.com/group/air-tight/browse_thread/thread/4f2184ddae0309d) may help you.